# Add next and previous button to Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am displaying some images on my picture gallery page.

On this page I am using a jquery lightbox to display images.

The lightbox is working fine,but it doesn't have next and previous buttons .
How can I add the next and previous buttons on those pages.

There are number of pages having the lightbox so I don't want a major change.
Can anyone suggest me how can I add next and previous buttons with little changes ?

Here is my aspx page code :

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
              <img src="9.jpg" alt="..." class="styleforimg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
              <img src="10.jpg" alt="..." class="styleforimg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
         <img src="11.jpg" alt="..." class="styleforimg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
      </div>

<div id="lightbox" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <button type="button" class="close hidden" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>Images/logo.png"  alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript file code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var $lightbox = $('#lightbox');

      $('[data-target="#lightbox"]').on('click', function (event) {
          var $img = $(this).find('img'),
              src = $img.attr('src'),
              alt = $img.attr('alt'),
              css = {
                  'maxWidth': $(window).width() - 100,
                  'maxHeight': $(window).height() - 100
              };

          $lightbox.find('.close').addClass('hidden');
          $lightbox.find('img').attr('src', src);
          $lightbox.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
          $lightbox.find('img').css(css);
      });

      $lightbox.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
          var $img = $lightbox.find('img');

          $lightbox.find('.modal-dialog').css({ 'width': $img.width() });
          $lightbox.find('.close').removeClass('hidden');
      });
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried something? And what lightbox have you used?

Comment: No, I didn't tried anything to add those buttons.And the code is displayed for your information,I used jquery lightbox

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ts2jku2x/8/ check this. It may help you

Comment: No, I don't want many more changes

Comment: You are using bootstrap modal to show the image. Why can't you use a library who built exactly for this? like http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: You are right @MoshFeu but I have designed many more pages more than 50 so I don't want to add a major change or change a jquery plugin although I just want the trick to be added in js

Comment: There is no trick - just code. That's all. It would be great if you provide link are accurate name of lightbox. There are million of them.

Comment: Sorry about this but it's seems, according to your code, that you know what you doing. Do you want that we will code for you?

Comment: No sir, I just want your suggestion to handle this.But I can't change the whole page structure as I've used the same in more than 50 pages :(